# My father, hence my mother, {is | are} catholic

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

A quite common structure in logical argument, is "*name1*, hence *name2*, *verb*". I am wondering about the correct form of the *verb* following such a structure when such a structure is a subject.

Should we always use plural, as if it was "*name1* and *name2*"? Or singular when *name1* (or both *name1* and *name2*?) is singular.

For example, which of the following is correct?

> My parents have the same religion. My father, hence my mother, is catholic.

or

> My parents have the same religion. My father, hence my mother, are catholic.

Comment: You may be trying to say "My father, and hence my mother, is catholic." This implies a causal relationship - because your father is catholic, and (implied) your mother follows what you're dad does, your mother is catholic. However, in the sentence, the "is catholic" applies to the father.

Comment: @AlexK +1 My father **is** Catholic, hence so is my mother

Comment: I think *My father, hence my mother* is fine. The OP states that such a construction is common in logical argument. Does someone have experience in the technical language of this field of philosophy to intelligently state they are wrong?

Comment: @Taladris: Can you cite a real example of this structure in the wild?

Comment: I see this as along the lines of *My parents have the same religion. My father, along with my mother, is **a** Catholic*. It might be clearer if your first sentence was *My parents each have the same religion*.

Comment: @AlexK: that's exactly what I want to say, using "hence" with the meaning of consequece. I don't really see any difference between "My father, and hence my mother, is catholic." and "My father, hence my mother, is catholic." though. But I am not a native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NB: the OP seems to have changed using **Catholic** (in the title, as in Rome) with **catholic** (in the question, as in *orthodoxy*). I am answering using catholic (as a noun) with no intended disrespect to Catholics]

The correct sentence of your two examples is

> My parents have the same religion. **My father, hence my mother, is catholic**.

The underlying sentence (main clause) is

> My father ... **is** catholic.

the subordinate clause is

> **hence my mother** *(is also)*
>   ***therefore*** my mother *(is also)*
>   ***thus*** my mother *(is also)*

making the subject of the sentence singular: **My father**.

Your use of **hence** is to mean **therefore**, **thus**, or **so** to show **causality**

**Hence** is an **conjunctive adverb** and is usually used to **connect the two clauses**

> My father is catholic **hence** my mother is also catholic
>   My father is catholic ***therefore*** my mother is also catholic
>
> My father is catholic **hence** my mother converted
>   My father is catholic ***therefore*** my mother converted

are correct to support the fact both parents have the **same religion**.

> My father **and** my mother **are** catholic
>   My parents **are** catholic **hence** my religion.

are also correct.

The sentence

> My father is catholic **hence** my mother

could mean that **because** your father is catholic he married your mother (for whatever reason)

Comment: Great explanation! For the reference, the title is not mine. I meant "catholic" in my example.